# Persistent PHP socket server

Tags: php, apache, sockets

I'm planning the development of a server written in PHP that can service socket requests. I use a free host (Heliohost) for testing, and it has cPanel. So far the only thing I've been able to think of to have a PHP script always running is to write a cron job that runs a bash script to check `ps` to see if the PHP is already running, and if it isn't, start it.

Is there a better way? Perhaps a way for a PHP thread to be started on an HTTP request and continue to run in Apache after the request has been serviced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost certainly not have success running persistent processes from Apache. It is designed to *prevent* that scenario (though if you can get to the `fork(2)` system call, it is probably do-able). I wouldn't recommend trying it though.

What would make more sense is if you use a hosting provider that gives you the ability to write your own `crontab(5)` specifications *and* run the PHP interpreter directly. Then you could just add a line to your `crontab(5)` like:

```
@reboot /path/to/php /path/to/script.php
```

Your script should probably perform the usual [daemonization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) tasks so that `cron(8)` isn't stuck waiting for your process to exit.

Comment: In fact, the cPanel interface prevents me from writing `@reboot` - I have to enter the five time fields. What command would you suggest I use to 'daemonize' the PHP interpreter?

Comment: Many C libraries provide a `daemon(3)` function -- can you call it easily from PHP? If not, can you write a little wrapper around it? If your system doesn't provide it, a `daemonize()` function is provided in the [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd ed book](http://www.apuebook.com/), file `daemons/init.c`.

Comment: What about just `/path/to/php /path/to/script.php &`? It becomes a backgrounded job, no?

Comment: I don't like that much but I cannot articulate why. :)